# Creating portable silverlight user control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls, portable-class-library

I'm trying to make a portable silverlight user control to be used in 2 separate projects: one is WP8 project, and the other is Windows Store.

In both of them I use xaml/C#, and based on silverlight. But the silverlight control I created works only in WP8 but not in Windows Store.

```
cannot convert from 'Controls.ProfileBox' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement'
```

Is it possible to create a silverlight class library that has a control usable in both projects?

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile your different project?

The easiest way to share your code between framework in c#/xaml is to compile the code in the required farmework:

You need to use the "Add as link" feature (Right click project -> Add Existing Item -> Change "Add" Button to "Add as link"). This way you have only one version of the source file, but you have N project for the N framework you want to compile.

Comment: Seems a good idea, I'll try it and accept your answer when my problem is solved. Thanks.